# Importing an openssl-created self-signed cert into a X509Certificate2 (Mono): Can encrypt, can't decrypt

Tags: c#, mono, openssl, rsa, x509certificate2

I'm in Fedora 14, MonoDevelop 2.4, Mono 2.6.7. I generated my self-signed cert thusly:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout mysitename.key -out mysitename.crt
```

Then I'm playing with encryption and decryption in C# thusly. I'm selecting the .crt file. The problem is that the [`X509Certificate2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.aspx) that's being created has no private key! Hence, the encrypt operation goes well, and decrypt bombs.

I'm probably running the openssl command wrong. Or is it some subtlety in creating the `X509Certificate2` object?

```
protected virtual void OnBtCertClicked (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (myCert == null)
        {
            myCert = new X509Certificate2(fchCert.Filename);
        }

        RSACryptoServiceProvider pubKey = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)myCert.PublicKey.Key;
        byte[] myBlob = UTF8Encoding.Default.GetBytes(tbDisplay.Buffer.Text);
        byte[] myEncryptedBlob = pubKey.Encrypt(myBlob, false);
        tbDisplay.Buffer.Text = System.Convert.ToBase64String(myEncryptedBlob, Base64FormattingOptions.InsertLineBreaks);
    }
    catch (Exception excp)
    {
        tbDisplay.Buffer.Text = excp.GetType().ToString() + "\n\n" + excp.ToString();
    }
}

protected virtual void OnBtCertDecClicked (object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (myCert == null)
        {
            myCert = new X509Certificate2(fchCert.Filename);
        }

        if (!myCert.HasPrivateKey)
            throw new CryptographicException("Certificate has no private key");

        RSACryptoServiceProvider privKey = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)myCert.PrivateKey;
        byte[] myEncryptedBlob = System.Convert.FromBase64String(tbDisplay.Buffer.Text);
        byte[] myBlob = privKey.Decrypt(myEncryptedBlob, false);
        tbDisplay.Buffer.Text = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myBlob);
    }
    catch (Exception excp)
    {
        tbDisplay.Buffer.Text = excp.GetType().ToString() + "\n\n" + excp.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide exception details? I reported a bug some time ago: https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=646491, seems similar

Comment: @djechelon: The HasPrivateKey property of the X509Certificate2 object is "false" after I import the .crt file. The exception is one I throw myself.

Comment: Oh yes, you CAN import the certificate, but with no private key. I believe this could be a bug in Mono that could be someway correlated with the one I posted. That's my thought. Have you tried in Windows? If it works, it's 100% a mono bug

Comment: No, same thing, no private key. I just copied the .exe to Windows and ran it there.

Comment: Now I tried recompiling the project through Visual Studio. Same thing.

Answer (score 7):

Create a PKCS#12 certificate:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in yourcert.crt -inkey yourprivkey.key -out newcert.p12
```

It should now contain the private key.

Answer (score 1):

A certificate only contains the public key. The OpenSSL command you use creates the key in the file **mysitename.key**. You have to load the key file separately.
AFAIR the generated key file should contain the base64 encoded RSA private key in PKCS#8 format- encapsulated by some text strings (*BEGIN/END RSA PRIVATE KEY*).

Comment: How do I import the .key file?